# Chilkat File Upload Getting Failed By Socket Error

Tags: c#, sockets, chilkat

Ok. i have developed a script.. that upload file to server..

it's working very nice on my computer and also on my vm..

but on my client pc.. it just shows following error every time.. Upload didn't go through for single time :(

here is the error:

```
        <fullHttpRequest>
      <domain>domain.com</domain>
      <port>443</port>
      <ssl>True</ssl>
      <openHttpConnection>
        <info>Opening connection directly to HTTP server.</info>
        <httpHostname>domain.com</httpHostname>
        <httpPort>443</httpPort>
        <tls>True</tls>
        <info>HTTPS secure channel established.</info>
      </openHttpConnection>
      <connectTime>Elapsed time: 1687 millisec</connectTime>
      <sendRequestHeader>
        <sendHeaderElapsedMs>0</sendHeaderElapsedMs>
      </sendRequestHeader>
      <sendRequestBody>
        <genMultipartFormData>
          <requestParam>
            <name>Data</name>
          </requestParam>
          <requestParam>
            <name>vidFile</name>
            <filename>C:\U3_2021-01-25-23-52-38_S0001.mp4</filename>
            <sendDataToOutput>
              <error>socket write aborted by application..</error>
              <error>Socket send aborted by application</error>
              <error>Failed to send TLS message.</error>
              <error>Failed to write bytes.</error>
              <error>Failed to write data to output.</error>
              <error>Failed to copy file data to output.</error>
            </sendDataToOutput>
          </requestParam>
        </genMultipartFormData>
        <sendBodyElapsedMs>56422</sendBodyElapsedMs>
        <error>Failed to send HTTP request body.</error>
      </sendRequestBody>
      <error>sendRequestBody failed.</error>
      <numBytesReceivedWhileSending>0</numBytesReceivedWhileSending>
    </fullHttpRequest>
```

i can't understand the error and thus what would be solution as well..

so, looking here for an help please?

best regards

Comment: Where ae you writing the file on server?  You probably do not have permission to write file in location on server.  It looks like the connection completed but failed when writing to server file system.

Answer (score 0):

"aborted by application" means that your application has a callback and your app's callback method is explicitly aborting the operation.   For example, if this is C++, then see https://chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/vcCkHttpRef.html#event0  or https://chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/vcCkHttpRef.html#event8
The similar applies for other programming languages, such as C#.  See https://chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csHttpRef.html#event8

Comment: thanks for your reply sir.. i am sorry to say, but there is no call back associated to that upload function and as stated it doing/working fine on my machine.. but not on client machine :(..

Comment: is it possible that any other service/software like antivirus/firewall may affect that?